# split exact complexes and biproducts

Tags: homological-algebra, abelian-categories

I have an split exact complex in an abelian category, that is, a chain complex which is exact and maps $s_n : C_n \to C_{n+1}$ st. $dsd = d$. I would like to prove that this implies that $C_n \cong  B_n \oplus B_{n-1}$.

I would like to do this by showing that $d_{n+1} s_n + s_{n-1}d_n = id_{C_n}$. Is this even true? If it is how do I prove it?[image: a picture showing the diagram]

Comment: Yes, a chain complex $C_\bullet$ is split exact if and only if the identity map of the complex is null-homotopic.
Take a look [here](http://spot.colorado.edu/~kearnes/S10/HW/hom3p5.pdf)

Comment: yes. but can you use $s_n$ for the chain homotopy, rather than defining $t_n$?

Comment: Oh, sorry! No, it is false in general. If you can wait till the end of the next week, I promise I will write a (class of) easy conterexample(s) and a sufficient condition for that to work, with a good amount of details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not true, in general. You can find a sufficient condition and a conter-example [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BzO3ibhx0xRkMDRMb0dXaHlPS0E/edit?usp=sharing).

**Note:** I assume few standard facts about abelian categories, that you can find in Freyd's *Abelian Categories*, Borceux' *Handbook of Categorical Algebra. Vol. 2* or in the last chapter of Aluffi's *Algebra: Chapter 0*.